# display user data after login php

Tags: php, sql

When a person is logged in, only he can see his personal data. How can I show him only his data in PHP?

```
<?php
    include_once("connection.php");
    if($_SESSION['id'])
    {
        $_SESSION = ['id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from `student` where 
        `id` = $_SESSION[id]");
        $show=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($show)
        {
            echo "welcome [username]";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Seems you have answered your own question?

Comment: What is the issue now ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
if($_SESSION['id'])
{
$SESSION = $_SESSION['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from `student` where 
`id` = '$SESSION'");
$show=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "welcome $show['username']";
}
```

It is better to set the username as a session variable on logging in, just like you set the user id. Then you won't be needing to get values from the db. U can just display the name from session.

```
$_session['username']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
are us setting the session data at some place if yes then get the session 
data with the keys you have saved in session such as:

echo $_SESSION['username'];
echo $_SESSION['email'];
echo $_SESSION['gender'];

if you did not set the data at any place first set it in session super 
global and then  get it Example:

 //set user data in session variable.
//get data from database or any other data source
// set in session
```

$_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line :

```
$_SESSION = ['id'];
```

By doing this, you overwrite the `$_SESSION` variable to an array that contains one string : `'id'`.

First of all, you need to populate the `$_SESSION` variables with the user data when he logs in. In your login page you should have something like this :

```php
if (... some condition that checks if the login and password are ok) {
  $_SESSION['id'] = $userFromYourDatabase['id'];
  $_SESSION['other_data'] = $userFromYourDatabase['other_field'];
}
```

Then in the page where you want to display the user's data :

```php
<?php
    include_once("connection.php");
    if($_SESSION['id'])
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from `student` where 
        `id` = {$_SESSION['id']}"); // Use curly braces to access array members inside strings
        $show = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // now $show is an array that holds the user data
        if($show)
        {
            echo "welcome {$show['username']}";
        }
    }
?>
```

That's to answer the question with the most basic solution possible. **But** be very careful when using variables inside SQL query strings. Here it's a `$_SESSION` variable, the only risk is if you manually put bad code (which it seems you are very likely to do) inside these variables. Or if you set `$_SESSION['id']` from user input (if you do `$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['something']` which would be very bad in any case). So just in case and as a good practice, consider using prepared statements Like explained here : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp